# what's the alternative to password grant now that it is deprecated? OAUTH 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

- I have a rest api built in spring boot.

  - A front end application in react.

I have users who should be able to log in and access their information e.g. orders. now in order for users to log in and register I thought it would be a best idea to use OAUTH. I started my research into ouath and found grant password be the perfect case. since the user be able to type in the their credentials (username and password) which goes to api service (also authorisation server) and that can authenticate and token will be passed but then I realised it is deprecated so I want to know whats the best grant type to use where user's username and password is passed for authentication and authorisation. or maybe i am missing something very simple that you guys can point towards.

Answer (score 29):

To summarize your situation: You have your own backend (server of some kind, such as a web application implementing a REST API) where users should be able to login using a username and password to obtain an access token giving their access to their own resources on the server, and they should be able to do this through your own frontend (client of some kind, such as smartphone app, desktop app, single-page application, etc.). The Resource Owner Password Grant solved your problem perfectly fine, but now it got deprecated :(

**Note**
It says in the OAuth 2.0 spec that *The OAuth 2.0 authorization framework enables a **third-party application** to obtain limited access [...]*. Your frontend is not really a third-party application in this case, but a first-party application, so you shouldn't really use OAuth 2.0, but it's better to use something well-documented instead of inventing your own solution to handle authorization, so just as you, I would still use OAuth 2.0.

**Simple solution (deprecated)** 
Continue using Resource Owner Password Grant. It does precisely what you want, and it was created for your specific case (frontend and backend come from the same "company").

Now they seem to have decided that OAuth 2.1 should not support first-party applications like this, but I would say it's still fine to use it for your case. It would be much worse if Google or someone else big OAuth 2.0 provider would support this Grant Type, because then developers might create their own frontend applications and let users login in on their frontend application by entering their Google username and password directly into the frontend application, i.e. revealing their Google credentials to the frontend developer. I imagine the reason they deprecate this Grant Type is to avoid such situations.

**Better solution (deprecated)**
Use Implicit Grant. In the frontend, when the user wants to login, redirect the user to the backend (i.e. open a webpage on the backend with a login form where the user can enter username and password), and after the user has successfully logged in on the backend, redirect the client back to the frontend with the access token. The benefit here is that the user only reveals her password to the backend application, and never to any client application. The drawback is that the backend must contain a webpage for the login form, making it a bit more complicated to implement compared to a pure REST API. And if you want to do this properly, the server should have a list of pre-registered clients with ids and secrets, but if you only have your own frontend you need to support I would say you can skip that or simply hardcode a client id in the backend application.

Unfortunately, this grant type has been deprecated as well...

**Proper solution**
Use Authorization Code Grant (with Proof Key for Code Exchange). This way is really similar to the Implicit Grant described above, but instead of redirecting the user back to the frontend with the Access Token, you redirect the user back to the frontend with an Authorization Code. The frontend can then send this Authorization Code to the backend and get back the Access Token.

What was described above was more or less only Authorization Code Grant. "with Proof Key for Code Exchange" is pretty much the same, but you also use a "key" to prove that you are the same client that redirects that user to the backend as and that trades the Authorization Code for an Access Token (the "with Proof Key for Code Exchange" part basically makes it more secure).

---

Here I've of course only described the overall idea, you need to look into the specifications to learn the details about the requests and responses you should send (what the body of the request should be, what status codes that are used, etc.).

Comment: Hello Peppe, I implemented PKCE flow successfully however facing an issue. Flow works fine on the first iteration however when user logs out and tries logging back in, auth server doesn't show up the login page and straight away issues new JWT token. Looks like auth server stores the session of the user somewhere. Both client and auth server belongs to me. Just to be clear, here is the flow.

Click Login > verifier & challenge generated > Auth server gives Login Form > Tom enters credentials > Token issued > log out

Click Login > verifier & challenge generated > Token issued > log out

Comment: Problem with this is, on the 2nd iteration, I can not login as a different user. On the logout I am invalidating the session and deleting the cookies as well .. here is the code snippet  --> (.logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID"))
                .permitAll()
                .and()

Comment: @Sachin You seem to have a very specific problem related to the OAuth 2.0 server you're using. It is more suitable that you to create a new question here on Stack Overflow where you describe the problem and provide more details on the OAuth 2.0 server.

Comment: Hi @Peppe L-G I've posted the new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75471187/spring-authorization-server-1-0-authorization-code-pkce

Comment: @Sachin Sorry, I have no experience of using Spring Authorization server 1.0, so I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: That's fine @Peppe L-G

Comment: `Proper solution` you suggest to him this is a better solution for him/her to fix, right? Is this more suitable for third-party apps? it seems it doesn't fit his case.

Comment: @Spring, It all depends on the use-case, I guess. OAuth is a framework for giving **third party websites/apps** access to your users' resources on your website. If that's what you need, then using `Authorization Code Grant (with Proof Key for Code Exchange)` is something I would encourage you to use. But if you just implement your own backend and your own frontend, then taking the shortcut and use the `Resource Owner Password Grant` for simplicity can be a feasible solution IMO.

Comment: @PeppeL-G, I think you are right about the `Proper solution`. They said here https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#name-resource-owner-password-gra . They don't allow to use `Resource Owner Password Grant` anymore on `OAuth2.1`  and they suggest an `Authorization Code Flow` to replace the `Resource Owner Password Grant`. To be honest, I am really confused. `Authorization Code Flow` is for `thrid-party` not `first-party with the same domain`.

Comment: @Spring, Using the `Authorization Code Flow` is always better, and it's a must to not use `Resource Owner Password Grant` when you need to support third-party apps, since that would expose your users' passwords to the third party apps. However, if you only need to support your own frontend app, then you don't need to use OAuth at all (since it's a framework for supporting third party apps), but it can still be good to use it with `Resource Owner Password Grant` so you implement authorization in an already documented way. But it's up to you.

Answer (score 10):

OAuth is specifically designed for **delegated authorization**, that is, authorization to access a resource on behalf of the user.
It is not designed for authentication. OpenID Connect (built-on top of OAuth) is designed for authentication.

In a delegated authentication/authorization environment, the authentication/authorization tasks are performed by specific independent services. If your application also manages authentication/authorization, maybe you don't need OpenID Connect/OAuth.

Anyway, the Resource Owner Password Grant is the worst delegated OAuth flow. It should be used in very rare legacy cases, and it is deprecated in OAuth2.1.
See [this article](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications) for more details.

The OAuth flow to use mostly depends on your application architecture.
Take a look [here](https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/which-oauth-2-0-flow-should-i-use) to determine which flow better fits your needs.